# create an android app that reads text from url

Tags: java, android, http, url, text

I found the answer
Include the following two lines in your “onCreate” method of the Main Activity:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();   
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

I created an android app that will read text from a URL and display the text on the screen. It crashes when my input is "http://web.njit.edu/~halper/it114/l2d.txt" but does nothing when my input is "http://web.njit.edu/~halper/it114/l2d.txt". I tried to add  `android.permission.INTERNET` to Manifest.xml and I still get the same result.
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
Thank you very much for your time

```
public void enter(View v) {

EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_file);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_main);

try {
URL url = new URL( input.getText().toString() );            
Scanner scan = new Scanner( url.openStream() );
while( scan.hasNext() ) 
tv.append( scan.nextLine() );   
}

catch(MalformedURLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Please post your LogCat.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17722)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5303)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: post all of your logcat.

Comment: do i just paste the text in here? it wont let me paste everything in here.

Comment: Edit you question and post all the relevant parts from your logcat there.

Comment: That's not actually a solution. It is a good idea to handle network calls asynchronously... I suppose if it's just for testing purposes it isn't terrible, but you'll hang your UI and get an ANR if you don't have an adequate internet connection, for example airplane mode or AT&T phone service...

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
    public String getTextFromTheMagicKingom() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        String url = "http://web.njit.edu/~halper/it114/l2d.txt";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```

And please correct the format in your comment. Have a nice day ._./

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Since HoneyComb we've no longer been allowed to make network calls on the UI thread because they're potentially slow and it would be silly to hang the UI while waiting on a server. You need to place your network code in a separate [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html), or use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), or a library such as Volley.

If this is just to test things out then you could also turn of [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) which is what disallows network access from that thread...

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); //Disabling StrictMode is not recommended. It is much better to make Asynchronous network calls...
```

You should have posted the code where you make the network request as well. It seems you're doing exercises for yourself, so I would recommend just using a Thread and using its runOnUiThread() method when you get your response. AsyncTask has much more functionality than you need...